# JavaScript RegEx Negative Lookbehind Without Doing a Negative Lookbehind in SuiteScript 2.x

Tags: javascript, regex, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I've put together a function in a custom module to handle trying to do a date/time formatting using the templates presented by NetSuite from the company preferences. However, I've had some trouble with handling the full name of the month and the hour in 12 hour format. If I use a negative lookbehind, it works just fine, but the problem is that it only works in scripts using 2.1, and there are too many in 2.0 to go around updating everything that needs this function from 2.0 to 2.1.

For example, these particular time templates:

```
Month D, YYYY
h:mm
```

The first will have proper output like:

```
February 11, 2022
```

But the second will have erroneous output:

```
h:15
```

I'm using the following RegEx to match the hour placeholder:

```
/^(?!nt)h/
```

And I know this works better where I can use it:

```
/(?<!nt)h/
```

I've tried searching around for a way to handle matching the "h" where it's not preceded by "nt", but they all keep pointing to the use of a negative lookbehinds to handle it, or are a bit unclear as to exactly how it's being done.

**EDIT**

Just to reduce confusion, the following are formats that could also be passed in to the function and need to be handled correctly:

```
YYYY/DD/MM h:m:s
MONTH DD, YYYY H-mm-ss
YYYYDDMMhms
YYYYDDMM-HHmmss
```

There's no one specific date/time template that can be passed in, so there's a specific need to be able to find H/h without it being a part of the word 'Month'.

Comment: Why do you check for `nt` absence before `h`? The strings have no `nt`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, because the strings could contain that. If you noticed early in the post, one of the potential string templates that could be applied is 'Month D, YYYY'.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capture group instead to capture what you want to keep, and match what you want to get out of the way.

The pattern matches `nth` that you don't want, and captures a `h` char.

In the code you could check if group 1 is present.

```
nth|(h)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DDe9GU/1)

For example in Javascript

```js
const regex = /nth|(h)/gi;
const str = `Month D, YYYY
h:mm

February 11, 2022
h:15
YYYY/DD/MM h:m:s
MONTH DD, YYYY H-mm-ss
YYYYDDMMhms
YYYYDDMM-HHmmss`;

const result = str.replace(regex, function(m, g1) {
  return g1 !== undefined ? "[" + g1 + "]" : m;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I did my own testing using that reg ex against the string template 'MONTH M/D/YYYY H:mm:ss', but it only return the 'nth' in the exec() results. It seemed to match just the 'h', but it gave a value of 'undefined'. I'm also assuming that this requires a couple lines to properly detect and replace? That it can't be currently used in the current single line match and replace I'm presently using?

Comment: @MichaelMcCauley You can check if group 1 exists, and if it does use for example replace with a callback function using the group 1 value. If there is no group 1 value available, then you return the full match. I have added a a code example.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I tested it out and it worked pretty nicely. Now, supposing I wanted to put this function into its own place to be easily referenced multiple times, and needed it to reference different string variables each time, how might one go about doing that?

Comment: @MichaelMcCauley Using Javascript for example, you can create a function like in this example https://jsfiddle.net/ze47mr8p/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/h(?!(?<=\bMonth)\b)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PbmlZB/2). *Details*:

- `h` - a `h` letter
- `(?!(?<=\bMonth)\b)` - a negativ lookahead that fails the match if immediatey to the eft of the current location there is a whole word `Month`.

If you do not care if the word `Month` is a whole word, you can use

```js
/h(?<!Month)/gi
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PbmlZB/3).